# How to read data from gpu memory ,not using memcpy?

Tags: gpu, vulkan, compute-shader

In vulkan API,how can we read data from gpu memory,like some data which were calculated by compute shader?

Comment: Typically one would use `vkCmdCopy*` and `vkMapMemory`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I use `vkMapMemory` to read data from devicememory ,and then,use `memcpy` copy data ,but it very very slow

Comment: Ah, then simply don't. You already received raw pointer with `vkMapMemory` that you can use directly.

Answer (score 3):

First wait on the fence related to the compute invocation. Then map the memory you wrote the result into and if the memory is not coherent you need to invalidate the range.

Read the data out of the pointer you got from the mapping operation.

Comment: Yes,those words you say were I used before, but I use `memcpy` copy data out of the pointer I got from the mapping operation ,and it very very slow .    `memcpy(kernel_Data.out_data, kernelBuff.outBuf.mapped, outSize*sizeof(float));`

Comment: @hlh077l you could try doing a buffer copy to a different memory pool with better host access. Not device local and preferably host cached.

Answer (score 1):

I've just gone through the same issue. I think @ratchet freak's comment 1 has got to the point. In my case, I was trying to transfer data from a texture(VkImage) to host memory. I used a linear buffer(VkBuffer) as the staging buffer. I originally used

```
VkMemoryPropertyFlags flag = VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT;
```

and found memcpy() very slow. Then I added VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_CACHED_BIT and the speed becomes about 10x.